# Вывод значения при создании класса в JS

Tags: javascript, классы

столкнулся с задачей и никак не могу сообразить как правильно реализовать класс.

есть класс

```
class MyClass {
   constructor() {
      let a = 0;
      this['methodName'] = () => a +++ a;
   }
}
```

как правильно его реализовать, чтоб при создании класса я получал переменную а, то есть

```
let classInstanse = new MyClass();
classInstanse == 1 // true
classInstanse == 3 // true
classInstanse == 5 // true
```

Изменять класс я не могу ( такое условие), могу только задать имя метода в this['methodName']

Answer (score 0):

суть где-то тут : [`Equality comparisons and sameness`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness), [`Object to primitive conversion`](https://javascript.info/object-toprimitive)

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    let a = 0;
    // или toString
    this['valueOf'] = () => a++ + a;
  }
}

let classInstanse = new MyClass();
console.log(classInstanse == 1) // true
console.log(classInstanse == 3) // true
console.log(classInstanse == 5) // true
```